# What is the maximum amount of electricity I can draw in 48 hours from a domestic supply?

Tags: energy, electricity, power

An electricity company is offering free electricity for a 48 hour period every week. The rate the rest of the time is very expensive.

How much power can be drawn from a domestic UK supply?

Would it be possible to draw enough energy in the 48 hour period to power my house for the rest of the week e.g. by charging a huge battery?

Bear in mind that the first time the battery is charged, the rest of the house would have to be powered too either for free or the initial charging could be paid for!

Day 1 Charge battery, power house
Day 2 Charge battery, power house
Day 3-7 Power house with battery

Day 8 Charge Battery, power house with battery
Day 9 Charge battery, power house with battery
Day 10-14 Power house with battery

Comment: You would need to state (and measure) your average consumption to answer this question. Also, it would probably be a collection of batteries rather than a mega battery.

Comment: The answer depends on (besides factors mentioned by count_to_10) what restrictions there are on the maximum power which can be drawn from the electricity supply to your house, the efficiency of the battery-charger and of the converter required to generate AC from your batteries.  These unknowns are not stated in your question.

Comment: Your bill likely tells you how man kW-hr you use. You can check what your panel size is (max amperage), multiply by voltage, multiply by 48 hours and see how close it comes. Likely it looks easy to do (I know my house is). But, you really are concerned with how many batteries you need, and the efficiencies of putting AC in ane getting it out, and then really how to use your panel capacity in a rational way. Not really a physics question - perhaps better for Home Improvement SE?

Comment: Depends on the service you have.  100 A?  200 A?

Comment: Just don't buy an electric or hybrid car.

Comment: dont spend money on the batteries, as soon as they detect your power consumption they will find a legal way to deny you the free days

Answer (score 2):

Typical domestic electricity consumption is 3,300kWh per year, or about 64kWh per week.  Gas consumption is 16,500kWh per year;  if you do not have a gas supply, your total power consumption would be about 380kWh per week.

The maximum current which can be drawn per house from the mains is 100A.  This is set by a fuse installed by your supplier close to your electricity meter.  The supply voltage is 230V so the maximum power which can be drawn is 23kW. During a 48h period you could draw 1104kWh of energy.

This is about 17x as much electricity as you would typically use in a whole week, including the weekend; if you use no gas the factor is about 3x.

So even allowing a generous factor for losses due to the efficiency of charging a battery from an AC supply (about 90%) and back again, you could very easily power your whole house from the storage of power at the weekend.